# Convert oracle code into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I have below code as part of oracle procedure ,Need help in converting into PostgreSQL procedure-

```
-- logic to send e-mail to multiple To'd users separated by ';'
  v_temp := replace(p_recepient,' ','');

  IF ( instr(v_temp,';') = 0) OR (instr(v_temp,';') < length(v_temp))
  THEN
    v_temp := v_temp || ';';
  END IF;

  v_pos := 1;
  WHILE (instr(v_temp,';',v_pos) > 0)
  LOOP
    v_name  := substr(v_temp,v_pos,instr(substr(v_temp,v_pos),';') - 1);
    v_pos   := v_pos + instr(substr(v_temp,v_pos),';');
    v_reply := utl_smtp.rcpt(conn,v_name);
  END LOOP;

  IF v_reply.code <> 250
  THEN
    utl_smtp.quit(conn);
    RETURN;
  END IF;

  -- logic to send e-mail to multiple CC's users separated by ';'
  v_temp1 := REPLACE(p_recpnt_cc,' ','');
  IF (instr(v_temp1,';') = 0) OR (instr(v_temp1,';') < length(v_temp1))
  THEN
    v_temp1 := v_temp1 || ';';
  END IF;

  v_pos1 := 1;
  WHILE (instr(v_temp1,';',v_pos1) > 0)
  LOOP
    v_name1  := substr(v_temp1,v_pos1/*1*/,instr(substr(v_temp1,v_pos1),';') - 1);
    v_pos1   := v_pos1 + instr(substr(v_temp1,v_pos1),';');
    v_reply1 := utl_smtp.rcpt(conn,v_name1);
  END LOOP;

  IF v_reply1.code <> 250
  THEN
    utl_smtp.quit(conn);
    RETURN;
  END IF;
```

As you see the above code has instr ,substr which are not there in PostgreSQL.

when I run above code as part of PostgreSQL procedure I am getting error as -

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 94:       IF ( instr(v_temp,';') = 0) OR (instr(v_temp,';') < le...
               ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 4028
```

Answer (score 0):

`instr` is provided by the SQL-standard `position` function.

`substr` is provided by the SQL-standard `substring` function.

See the [documentation on string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html).